# Put computer to sleep on battery, but wake up when power is restored?

Tags: windows, sleep

I have a server that is UPS backed - I don't think the UPS is managed. However Windows detects that it is on battery, and I can have Windows go to sleep after 1 minute when this happens.

However I would like to have it automatically wake from sleep when power is restored, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check for a setting in the BIOS that turns on the computer when power is set. I have a PC that will do this but it is very much dependent on the motherboard and the BIOS.

That way, the computer will always come on when power becomes available.

I can't think of any other options without having a secondary computer (could even be a Raspberry Pi!) that could run for a long time on it's own power but check the status of the UPS (presumably it has a USB connection if your main server knows that mains power has gone off). When it finds that main power is available, it could send a Wake On LAN packet to the server. You'd need to set up the Pi to also send a shutdown as well of course when the UPS signals going to battery.